# Get parent node based on some condition in ruby

Tags: ruby

i have a hash like below.

```
prop =  {"Pets"=>[]},
     {"Misc"=>["HOA Frequency: (C101)"], "photos"=>nil},
     {"Legal and finance"=>["HOA fee: $300.0"], "photos"=>nil}
```

I need to get Legal and finance nodes based on some condition.

I tried like below.

```
prop.find { |feature| feature.keys.include?("Legal and finance") }
```

But sometimes HOA fee will be under different node. It might be in "Finance" or "Legal and Finance" or "Home Finance" like

```
{"Finance"=>["HOA fee: $300.0"], "photos"=>nil} or
{"Home Finance"=>["HOA fee: $300.0"], "photos"=>nil}
```

So i need to get that complete node by checking whether any node contains text as "HOA Fee" as value.

Comment: What exactly is the expected return value? The hash including the `finance` key/value pair, a hash only including the `finance` key/value pair or just the value?

Comment: _"i have a hash like below"_ – that syntax is invalid.

Comment: "I have a hash like below" -- this is a common first sentence here on SO. But it's a mistake to think you need to construct an elaborate data structure and then attempt to pull stuff out of it, only to throw away all intermediary transformations. Instead of constructing the hash to begin with, I recommend that you answer your question directly from the data store, most likely via ActiveRecord queries. Overall this will be cleaner, shorter, and more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prop.find do |feature|
  feature.values.flatten.compact.any? do |value|
    value.include?("HOA Fee")
  end
end
```

This is a very messy data structure, however.

I would strongly advise you to refactor the code to store data in well-defined objects, not hashes of hashes of arrays...

Comment: Totally agree on _very messy data structure_.

Comment: @Tom Lord. This is the way i wanted to retrieve its value.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
prop.find { |hash| hash.keys.any? { |key| key.downcase.include?('finance') } }
#=> { "Legal and finance" => ["HOA fee: $300.0"], "photos" => nil }
```